# Why does this one-line function work in zsh but not bash, and how can I fix it for bash?

Tags: linux, bash, zsh

I figured out the answer as I was researching how to phrase the question, but it may be useful for somebody. I use zsh and both my .zshrc and my .bashrc have `source $HOME/.alias` in them. Here is the old, problematic `~/.alias`

```
rl() { grep -v "$1" "$2" > /tmp/rl.txt && mv /tmp/rl.txt "$2" }
...
```

It worked fine in zsh, but in bash I got an unexpected end of file error, and `rl` was undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fixed `~/.alias` that works in both zsh and bash is

```
rl() { grep -v "$1" "$2" > /tmp/rl.txt && mv /tmp/rl.txt "$2"; }
...
```

Bash just requires a semicolon after the last command in a one-line function declaration.

Comment: By the way, `rl`, as defined above, is used this way: `rl someword somefile.txt`, and it will remove lines containing "someword" from "somefile.txt".

Comment: `sed -i -e '/someword/d' somefile.txt` will delete all line with occurrences of _someword_ in the file _somefile.txt_ in-place (the -i option)

Answer (score 2):

You can use `sed` in the function to avoid making a copy of the file and then moving it over the original file.

```
rl() { sed -i -e "/$1/d" "$2"; }
```

The `-i` flag edits file file in-place, and makes a backup *if* you supply an extension. With no extension it just edits in-place.